# Timer event does not fire

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to write a very simple code in Access-VBA. I want to write the time in a button caption, but my code does not work.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
 Me.TimerInterval = 0
 Befehl94.Caption = Time
End Sub
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the TimerInterval on the form's properties menu rather than the "Form_Timer" event as this is triggered based on the value entered in the forms properties.

The value is in milliseconds so 1000 will cause the timer to run every 1 seconds, the "Time" function is also incorrect, your code would be more like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    Befehl94.Caption = TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()))

End Sub
```

Using TimeSerial will give you just the time whereas "Now()" on it's own will give you TimeDate, you could use the "Format" command instead but I prefer TimeSerial

Comment: Thanks,I did it .I set the timeinterval to 1000 nad write your code but it doesnot work :(

Comment: another thing,I have a seub form and main form when I put this code on my sub form for a button on my sub form it works corectly but for main form and a button on it it doesn't work,Do you know why?

Comment: @iav-babak Difficult to say, in theory should be the same, try referring to the button via the form e.g "Forms!Mainform!ButtonName.Caption"

Answer (score 1):

You need an interval of greater than zero. Setting it to zero disables the timer. Also you can start and stop the timer with the Enabled property.

Separately (and more pertinently), you don't need a Timer to achieve what you want, you can simply write:

```
   Befehl94.Caption= Now()
```

To show the date and time. Investigate the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb216dct%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function to format the date/time as required.

Comment: thnk you for your answer,honestly I want to test Timer function for another purpose